# Unable to pass derived Compare to std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, c++11, std, priority-queue

I need to pass a derived comparator to `std::priority_queue`, but for some reason the base class' operator() is being called.

Here is a minimal code that shows this behavior:

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual bool operator() (int l, int r) const {
        cout << "Should not be called" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    virtual ~Base() {}
};
class A : public Base { 
    public:
    bool operator() (int l, int r) const override {
        cout << "Should be called!!!!";
        return l < r;
    }
};
int main() {
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, Base> pq((A()));
    pq.push(1);
    pq.push(2);
    pq.push(3);
    pq.push(0);
    cout << pq.top();
    return 0;
}
```

[The code is available on ideone as well](https://ideone.com/6aZluP)

Note that I cannot use `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, A>`, because I have other subclasses for `Base`, and that will result in a lot of code duplication<sup>1</sup>.

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass a comparator to the priority_queue that will be used during its life time?

---

(1) I know I can bypass the code duplication issue by using template functions that accept `priority_queue<int,vector<int>, T>` - but I really rather not to.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why slicing? The constructor is accepting `const Compare&`. I am reluctant to believe it is later saved by value in a std library class.

Comment: Sorry en.cppreference.com was down for a moment.

Comment: @amit It has to be saved by value internally. If the container was just saving a reference, the code you have in the question would be undefined behavior because the lifetime of the comparator instance you pass to the container ends when the constructor call returns.

Comment: Of course it's saved by value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard specifies `Compare comp` as value members of the class template in *23.6.4.1*. The constructors are said to:

> Initializes comp with x and c with y (copy constructing or move
>   constructing as appropriate);

Therefore you have slicing, even if the parameter type is actually a `const Compare&`.

To work around that, you could implement a pimpl-wrapper for the comparator. This wrapper would internally keep a `Base&` to the actual comparator, and in it's non-virtual `operator()` simply call the `virtual operator()` of the `Base` / `A` comparator.

Please think carefully about the lifetime of your `A` Object. Depending on the needed state of your Comparator, you could implement a [virtual `clone`-method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17292813/620382) in `Base`. And keep `Base` as a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` in your `PimplCompare` - which you clone in it's copy-ctor. Or you keep it as `std::shared_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: I believe [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) is in error when it states for (2) "Move-constructs the comparison functor comp with std::move(compare). In all constructors, compare is handed by `const Comp&`. `std::move(compare)` would be of type `const Comp&&`, but the move-constructor would take a `Comp&&` - so it would call the copy-ctor. libstdc++ does not seem to do any moving on the comparators.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor takes a `const Compare&` which would not cause any slicing when passing the object to the function but we then have in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue)

> Copy-constructs the underlying container c with the contents of cont. Copy-constructs the comparison functor comp with the contents of compare.

Since a copy is happening and the template type is `Base` you are only going to copy and store the `Base` part of the `A` object.

You will have to wrap the comparison object in some sort of wrapper and expose a non virtual `operator ()` that will call the virtual `operator()` of the type passed to the `priority_queue` constructor.

Comment: _"you are only going to copy and store the Base part of the A object."_ Isn't that exactly _slicing_?

Comment: The question is "What am I doing wrong?". Or to be more explicit, how can I pass a comparator to the priority_queue that will be used during its life time?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I reworded it to clear up that I meant it was not slicing when be ing passed to the function.